# The connection between Azure Storage and Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, rstudio

I am currently using Windows Azure Virtual Machine to run RStudio,

My virtual machine is Windows Server R2 2012, which is an add-on service on Azure.

Also I have a Azure storage account.

I'm trying to run RStudio on the virtual machine, which will need to frequently access data to and from the azure storage account.

It would be greatly convenient for me if I could access the data easily using the RStudio, such as command lines or so.

Other methods are fine too, but using Import/export service on the blob storage seems too much of work when processing so much data.

Please help, I'm new at this computing and need to use Azure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are interested in using a command shell within a VM to perform file operations (copy etc) between the CM and blob storage. If so you have a number of different options:
- AZCopy
- PowerShell Set-AzureStorageBlobContent and Get-AzureStorageBlobContent
- node.js CLI tools

Hope this helps.

Jason